# LESS и случайное число

Tags: less

Может ли *LESS* сгенерировать случайное число, чтобы потом задать с его помощью случайный цвет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может. *LESS* может выполнять *JavaScript*, поэтому сгенерировать случайный цвет можно так:

```
.randomColor(){
  @randomColor: `Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)`;
  @colorHex: e(@randomColor);
  @color: ~"#@{colorHex}";
}

body {
    .randomColor();
    background-color: @color;
}
```

[Источник.](https://gist.github.com/juanbrujo/7e4e17428dc8881d0e7e)